# FTPS client certificate authentication

Tags: linux, ftp, certificate, ftps, client-certificate

I'm installing FTPS server on debian with certificate-based authentication. I've set up ProFTPd and configured it to use TLS and a certificate (for testing purposed I use a self-signed one).

Now I'd like to test it. To do it I want to connect authenticating by certificate. Do you know how to do it using lftp? (It may be any other command-line client, but I started with lftp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `ssl:cert-file` and `ssl:key-file` options.